# How to change the QGIS edit cursor and node icons?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, gui

Two things I really dislike at QGIS, are the "fat" node icons (when editing lines) and the cursor which cover the object below and make it impossible to accurately move a node.  Is it possible to change that? Or is it worth to give a feature request a try?

I realy like JOSM in that way (you can see the line oriantation, the middle between two nodes with the possibility to add another with a single click and there are just dots for every node - perfect!):

[image: JOSM Line Edit]

QGIS line edit:

[image: QGIS Line Edit]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a matter of personal preferences. I work well with the "fat" node icons when using the node tool. It would be nice to have the line direction also, so you don't have to add that by adding a marker line creating a composite style.

[image]

I think the double click for adding nodes, is because a single click is to snap to a node or a line (snapping to a line marks the ending nodes).

The default thin cross hair cursor does not cover my nodes up.

I would give a feature request a chance, especially if you also can find funding for the work. I can see you changed the vertex marker to a semi transparent circle (Settings > Digitizing > Vertex markers). It would be very nice, in the settings, to also be able to set the style of the node icon when editing. But I think the "fat" node icons are useful when you select several nodes by clicking on a line or dragging a square across several nodes.

Using QGIS 2.6.0.

[image]